# Printing to an Intermec mobile printer from web application

Tags: barcode-printing, intermec

Hello I have purchased a new Intermec CK3R Mobile computer and a  PB50 Printer.  I am developing a inventory check in system that will work in the following way

Background

- Basically it is a single page ASP.NET MVC application with some JavaScript.
- There are two form fields (Part Number,  Serial number)

Flow

- After the part number is scanned, focus is moved to Serial number.
- After serial number is scanned the data is sent to the server via AJAX Post
- Server does extensive validation
- if it passes:    Part number and serial number pair are entered into a database.  The new unique id, part number and serial number is passed back to the client.
- If it fails:   and error code & message is returned back to the client

So here is the question.  On a successful validation I would like a print job to be sent to the PB50 so the box can be labeled.  The label should have the unique ID in barcode,  and the part number in text.

I need a starting point to go from. I would be great if I could use JavaScript to send the print job.

I found http://www.hjgode.de/dev/activex1.htm which is an older example.  I want to be sure i am going about this in the most efficient manner.